# How some of these `data` definitions in Haskell get evaluated

Tags: haskell

I'm looking at some examples to see how more complex `data` definitions work, such as these....

```
data DualMap a b = DualMap (Map a b) (Map b a)
data Store s a = Store (s -> a) s deriving Functor
data Fold a b = forall x . Fold (x -> a -> x) x (x -> b)
data Pair a b = Pair !a !b
type Rule m a = (m -> a) -> a
data RingZipper a = RingZipper {
    before :: V.Vector a,
    focus  :: a,
    after  :: V.Vector a
} deriving(Eq, Generic, NFData)
```

I have a few quick questions on some of them.

First, the meaning of `[a] a [a]` here:

```
data Universe a = Universe [a] a [a]
```

Next, not sure how the following works. It seems to say create a list out of all the same elements in a strange way. By that I mean I don't understand what it means to pass in `BExpr`.

```
data BExpr = BoolConst Bool
           | Not BExpr
           | BBinary BBinOp BExpr BExpr
           | RBinary RBinOp AExpr AExpr
```

That was from [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language).

Next, wondering what `[a] [(a,a)]` means in [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellForMaths-0.4.9/docs/src/Math.Algebra.Group.CayleyGraph.html#Digraph), or how it gets resolved.

```
data Digraph a = DG [a] [(a,a)] deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

Some others I don't have questions on...

```
type Monomial coefficient exponent  = (coefficient, exponent)
```

https://github.com/dmjio/miso/blob/master/src/Miso/Router.hs

```
data Router a where
  RChoice       :: Router a -> Router a -> Router a
  RCapture      :: FromHttpApiData x => (x -> Router a) -> Router a
  RQueryParam   :: (FromHttpApiData x, KnownSymbol sym)
                   => Proxy sym -> (Maybe x -> Router a) -> Router a
  RQueryParams  :: (FromHttpApiData x, KnownSymbol sym)
                   => Proxy sym -> ([x] -> Router a) -> Router a
  RQueryFlag    :: KnownSymbol sym
                   => Proxy sym -> (Bool -> Router a) -> Router a
  RPath         :: KnownSymbol sym => Proxy sym -> Router a -> Router a
  RPage         :: a -> Router a
```

And finally from [here](https://github.com/ekmett/structures/blob/master/src/Data/Vector/Set/Fusion.hs), how the `MergeL sa sb a` vs. `MergeR sa sb a` get selected, I don't see it.

```
data MergeState sa sb a
  = MergeL sa sb a
  | MergeR sa sb a
  | MergeLeftEnded sb
  | MergeRightEnded sa
  | MergeStart sa sb
```

Comment: I don't have time now for a detailed answer (being on phone doesn't help), but most of those things you've asked about are simply types which you pass values of to the constructor. For example `Universe` is a constructor function that takes a list of `a`s, a single `a` and another list, and produces a `Universe a` value. And all `Universe a` values can be made this way. For definitions with the pipe character, the pipe separates different constructors which can make those values. Haskell keeps track of which constructor was used for each value, and can for example pattern match on it.

Comment: There are too many unrelated questions in this post.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_declarations) and [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes) should probably help (or any other Haskell tutorial, really).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Algebraic Data Types

Algebraic data types are what you want to look at, and they can be used to define data such as trees, algebraic expressions and parsing instructions.

- **`data Universe a = Universe [a] a [a]`**

This defines a new data type Universe that holds data of type `a` (this can be any type) and you construct with a list, an element, and another list. It does not say much as is, and I can't come up with an example as to when you'd use it, but if you have one I can explain it to you. (EDIT: Look at first comment) It is important to note that you can do pattern matching with it, so you could have a function such as:

```
    f :: Universe a        -> a
    f (Universe _ 0 _)      = 0
    f (Universe (x:xs) z ys = x
```

- **`data BExpr = BoolConst Bool
         | Not BExpr
         | BBinary BBinOp BExpr BExpr
         | RBinary RBinOp AExpr AExpr`**

This again defines a new data type that is recursive and it's of the most used type. The pipe `|` constructor means "or", in the sense that your type BExpr can either be:

- `BoolConst Bool` : a boolean constant (True/False), defined in some other type
- `Not BExpr` : a negation of another expression
- Some other expression containing an operator and two expressions to apply it to

For a simpler example, think of

```
Data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

This is how most trees are defined: your data can either be a Leaf, or a node containing two trees and some data.

Look at these two links for more info:
[Haskell Wiki: Algebraic data type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type)
[School of Haskell: Evaluating Data Types](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/introduction-to-haskell/2-algebraic-data-types)

- `data Digraph a = DG [a] [(a,a)] deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)`
  This is exactly the same as the `Universe a`, It holds some data and it is constructed giving it a list of `[a]` and a list of tuples `(a,a)`. Again, you can use pattern matching.

For the last one, again they're different ways to call a constructor for that type

Comment: `Universe [a] a [a]` sure looks like a list [zipper](https://wiki.haskell.org/Zipper), that is, a list with a "focused element".  The name isn't evocative of it but that pattern is very familiar: elements to the left, focused element, elements to the right.

Comment: @luqui I've used `Universe` and relatives a lot recently. The idea is that if you have a cellular automaton operating on a 1D universe, you can represent that as a list zipper. This construction is _extremely_ useful with comonads; see e.g. https://kukuruku.co/post/cellular-automata-using-comonads/ for more information.

Comment: @bradrn oh yeah, I read dan piponi's original about that.  It's really cool.